# Recovering data from a non-booting HDD laptop hard drive

Tags: mount, data-recovery, gparted, boot-repair, ntfs-3g

I am trying to recover data from my HDD 500 GB Seagate Momentus 7200.2 internal hard drive i use in my Dell Studio XPS 1640 with Vista Home Premium.

Here are the things I have tried:

1. I tried rebooting; it always hangs on the page with the Green Microsoft loading bar screen and goes back to rebooting again and keeps repeating in a loop and never loads top the page where I log in. I tried booting with my original vista re-installation disk to repair Hard drive errors but no luck.
2. I did start-up repair, `chkdsk c: /f /r` (C is my active primary partition) , I did memory diagnostic test, I ran all system diagnostic tests, sfc /scannow, etc. Everytime I run checkdisk it takes extremely long like it will take days, so I end up using `chkdsk C: /f /r /x` which made the process faster. I always have bad sectors, and mostly unreadable indexes that are "being processed" which means repairing I guess.
3. I decided to order a cable 2.5" SATA hard drive to USB 3.0 , In that case i figured i wont need any power cable, (12V) as this is 2.5" HDD needs 5V whic can be supplied through USB. I was hoping it wont delete any data off my hard drive. I WAS ABLE TO get to my files in a crap laptop which always freezes, I plugged it in there and even though I was concerned about permission to access things as the HDD had a password on it, I was surprisingly able to get to every single file in it.

   UNTIL I went to library to move all files. It didn't let me get in that folder as I forgot I was not admin in library but just a guest account with no rights over any folder to move which can be controlled by admin, even though it was my own hdd. I was looking to move them off my HDD to move into a usb flash drive.

   So I came home and borrowed one of the laptops of my friend to be safe and i end up seeing my hard drive showing up but NO SIZE or name indicated, and when i click on it, it sees like RAW disk and saying please format to start using it. I have data in it and didn't wanna format it of course.

   My machine is out of warranty, and sick of hearing DELL telling me to go to technician because i was able to see those files but i can't even with the cable, i only able to connect it but not get to the files.

   I searched my warranty on Seagate but it is out of warranty too of course.
4. I came across one of these threads suggesting to use Ubuntu live CD and I immediately burnt Ubuntu 16.2 onto an 8GB usb flash drive with Rufus. I tried to see if my hard drive will show up but NO luck, my hard drive doesn't show up in computer inside Ubuntu at all.

I tried

```
sudo /bin/bash > to be root i guess, or admin
mkdir /media/disk
mount -t ntfs-3g /dev/sda3 /media/disk -o force
```

As I know my HDD primary partition was NTFS. I got this:

```
The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
The file system wasn't safely closed on Windows. Fixing.
ntfs_attr_pread_i: ntfs_pread failed: Input/output error
Failed to read NTFS $Bitmap: Input/output error
NTFS is either inconsistent, or there is a hardware fault, or it's a
SoftRAID/FakeRAID hardware. In the first case run chkdsk /f on Windows
then reboot into Windows twice. The usage of the /f parameter is very
important! If the device is a SoftRAID/FakeRAID then first activate
it and mount a different device under the /dev/mapper/ directory, (e.g.
/dev/mapper/nvidia_eahaabcc1). Please see the 'dmraid' documentation
for more details.

#fdisk -l
```

(to see if my disk will show and it showed up)

I used `gparted` and scanned the every hard drive in my system and showed my internal hard drive.
(I connected my non-booting HDD hard drive internally as it didn't show up at all through USB to SATA connection)

I am very curious how I am supposed to use gparted in terminal after I typed it and after i see my hard drives. Can I get to my files in it and mount the data into another USB flash drive to move my files off it?

The only problem I have in the list that shows my hard drive after gparted typed in terminal is, the actual hard drive that has my data in it HAS Input/Output Error (I/O Error) and it has a red exclamation sign next to it. And when I right click> Information, following shows up as

```
**Warning:** *Unable to read the contents of this file system!
Because of this some operations may be unavailable.
The cause might be a missing software package.
The following list of software packages is required for NTFS file system support: ntfs-3g / ntfsprogs.*
```

I don't have a second HDD to clone this Non-booting HDD but I do have a few new 128GB flash drives.

Comment: Your drive is reporting an I/O error. In *most* cases, this means your hard drive is toast and any data on it is more or less irrecoverable. Try to make an image of your hard drive and work off of that. If you can't even do that, there's nothing you can do, sorry.

Comment: The GParted ntfs info is saying that you need to install ntfs-3g and ntfssprogs packages to be able to read the drive. In order to do that you will need to install ubuntu directly onto a flash drive or an external hard drive, and then install the packages on there.

Comment: # brndn2k , I installed ubuntu 16.04 LTS to have my live ubuntu session in USB. but still i can't figure this out.
I recently tried macrium reflect hard disk image but it didnt see my hard disk connected with SATA to usb cable.